# nhibernate - find object with the same list

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

Let us say I have an object that contains an IList of some other objects. Is it possible to find objects with the same IList efficiently? What would you use HQL or ICriteria. I can’t see an easy way using SQL.

Thanks.

Christian

PS:

Just to clarify. I have a class A which contains:

```
public virtual string Text { get; set; }
```

Class B contains:

```
public virtual IList<A> As { get; set; }
```

I would like to find every object that contains:

a, a1, bla

in this order. The comma indicates the particular Text elements in list As.

PPS:

Using ICriteria’s find by example does not seem to work:

```
NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria(typeof(B)).Add(Example.Create(b)).List();
```

Here b is an instance of B where the list contains particular instances of A

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Linq to NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.0.GA/NHibernate.Linq-1.0.0.GA-bin.zip/download). I've had success with it.

From there you can do a join. You may join on multiple properties if you need to. This may not be a perfect example, because I just made it up, but it should give you the idea.

```
var query =
    from c in customers
    join e in employees
        on new { c.Id, c.Address1 } equals new { e.Id, e.Address1 }
    select new
    {
        c.Id,
        c.Name,
        c.Address1,
        e.StartDate
    };
```

You can use LinqPad (google it) to test

For more help with NHibernate, I have read many good things on [Ayende's site](http://ayende.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need several things. You need tomake sure you've mapped As as a `list` so that you can have an index against which you can test order. You need to do a join to A

So you can do

```
NHibernateSession.Current.CreateCriteria<B>()
    .CreateAlias("As", "a")
    .Add(Example.Create(b))
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but it did not work. I am currently using Fluent NHibernate and this mapping: mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.As).Table("BAs");

Comment: This does now work either: mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.As).Table("BAs").AsList(index => index.Column("SortOrder"));

Comment: What is the SQL that it generates or does it error out? What does it mean 'it doesn't work'?

Comment: The problem is that the finding by example does not work. It generates:  SELECT this_.Id as Id6_0_ FROM Bs this_ WHERE (1=1). I would like to find any object examples that have the same list of As.

Comment: Actually when I use the alias you suggested it joins but the query still contains WHERE (1=1) which must be wrong !?

Comment: When I get stumped with an Nhibernate query I start with a SQL query. How would you write what you would want to achieve in SQL? Please update the question when you've figured it out.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to write this in sql ... i imagined that creating an example object with a list and then using icriteria to find objects with this list should be possible.